# What could cause different CSS behaviour from a PC to another?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application which displays as expected in both Google Chrome and Internet Explorer locally.

However, once deployed through TFS to the remote server, the view only displays correctly using Google Chrome?

**Deployed with Chrome:**

[image: Deployed with Google Chrome]

**Deployed with IE:**

[image: Desployed with Internet Explorer]

I would have doubted about IE compatibility button if I would have visited the page using a different workstation. But, I always and only use my own attributed workstation.

So, what could change so drastically so that the page displays conveniently using IE locally by pressing the [F5] key in Visual Studio and simply running the Web application, and make it screw the CSS up once it is deployed?

I use:

- Internet Explorer 9
- Visual Studio 2010
- Windows 7
- IIS 7.5
- Google Chrome 39.0.2171.71 m
- TFS 2010

Below is my CSS and CSHTML files (at least what I judged important to include, and removed what I think is not).

**Site.css**

```
html {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: solid 10px #000;
    color: #000;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header, footer, hgroup,
nav, section {
    display: block;
}

.float-left { float: left; }
.float-right { float: right; }
.clear-fix:after {
    content: ".";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* main layout
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#body {
    background-color: #fff;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

#body a { color: #000; }

#body a:hover {
    background-color: #a2998a;
    color: #005596;
}

#body a:link { color: #000; }
#body a:active { color: #000; }
#body a:visited { color: #000; }

.main-content {
    background: url("../Images/accent.png") no-repeat;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.email-counter {
    display: block;
    font-size: 13em;
    font-family: Consolas, Arial, monospace;    
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.mailbox-title {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000 !important;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.mailbox-title a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.mailbox {
    border: 3px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;    
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 32.66%;
}

.mailboxes-indicators { height: 400px; }
header .content-wrapper { padding-top: 20px; }
footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    font-size: .8em;
    height: 100px;
}


/* site title
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.site-title {
    font-family: Rockwell, Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    line-height: 600%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.site-title a, .site-title a:hover, .site-title a:active {
    background: none;
    color: #c8c8c8;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.site-title .column { display: inline-block; }
.site-title #logo {
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
}

.site-title #page-title-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 133%;
}

.site-title #page-title-container #page-title {
    color: #000;    
    font-size: 4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: -15px;
}

.site-title #page-title-container #latest-refresh-date-time {
    font-size: xx-large;
    text-align: center;
    top: -15px;
}

#sum-of-emails-from-all-mailboxes {
    border: 3px solid #000;
    left: -60px;    
    position: relative;
    width: 110%;
}

#sum-display-name {
    background-color: #cadaa9;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 2.5em;    
    position: relative;
}

#sum-of-emails { font-size: 8em; }
```

**DisplayIndicators.cshtml**

```
@model IndicateursCourriels.ViewModels.CustomerServiceIndicatorsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DisplayIndicators";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section header {
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="site-title">
            <div class="column">
                <div id="page-title-container">
                    <div id="page-title">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ViewTitle)
                    </div>
                    <div id="latest-refresh-date-time">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.LatestRefreshDateTime)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column float-right">
                <div id="sum-of-emails-from-all-mailboxes">
                    <div class="mailbox-title">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SumOfEmailsFromAllMailboxesDisplayName)
                    </div>
                    <div id="sum-of-emails" class="email-counter">            
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SumOfEmailsFromAllMailboxes)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div class="mailboxes-indicators">
    <div class="mailbox">
        <div class="mailbox-title">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstMailboxName)
        </div>
        <div class="display-label" style="text-align: center;">
            <span class="email-counter" 
                  style="background-color: @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstAlertLevelColour)">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstEmailCount)
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mailbox">
        <div class="mailbox-title">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SecondMailboxName)
        </div>
        <div class="display-label">
            <span class="email-counter" 
                  style="background-color: @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SecondAlertLevelColour)">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SecondEmailCount)
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mailbox">
        <div class="mailbox-title">
            <a href='@Url.Action("EmailIndicatorManualInput", "CustomerServiceIndicators")'>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ThirdMailboxName)
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="display-label" style="text-align: center;">
            <span class="email-counter" 
                  style="background-color: @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ThirdAlertLevelColour)">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ThirdEmailCount)
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **EDIT**

As per comment by [**Jonathan Sampson**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54680/jonathan-sampson), the local and remote document modes are actually different.

- Local Document Mode: **IE9**
- Remote Document Mode: **IE7**

So I did change the Document Mode to IE7 for my local WebApp instance, and have gotten the same display as the remote instance.

Now the questions are:

1. What might I do to force IE9 Document Mode? Or else,
2. how to ensure it displays correctly in either modes?

Comment: Getting any errors in the dev console?

Comment: Everyone's got different font rendering engines, everyone's got different interpretations of w3c specs, blah blah blah

Comment: @MarcB Don't think that is important here, Will says it works in IE on local machine prior to deployment.

Comment: I would investigate the browser cache. Empty it and try it from TFS again. Also verify zoom levels. It looks like the div containers are overflowing which makes me think it might be a marginal sizing issue.

Comment: Is the local view going through IIS or through Visual Studio's web server? There may be security differences between a remote view and local view in IE.

Comment: @JBKing: I didn't think this would make any difference. Anyway, I always run through VS Web Server locally, as I run the app with the [F5] key, and the Web settings in the project properties are set to use VS WebServer and and NTLM Authentication.

Comment: @RabidDog5150: I shall try after having emptied the browser cache. It is true that this sometimes makes funny things because of the cache. I have already had some weird behaviour because of it through Chrome. Anyway! When you say try from TFS again, I guess you mean to try the remotely deployed version of the app after having emptied my browser cache, don't you? Besides, what do you mean by verifying the zoom levels? I'm really not a designer and still have a lot to learn to use CSS and the different `div` and `span`, etc. adequately, as you might see in my code.

Comment: @DavidG: Absolutely no error shown anywhere, except if I'm misunderstanding what the console is. I actually can't or don't know if I may access IIS on the remote server where the application sits.

Comment: Press F12 and check the Document Mode locally, and remotely. You may be getting a different document mode when viewing locally.

Comment: It could be something like IIS refusing to serve up CSS/fonts/JS/etc, or some sort of XSS security issue. Or as @JonathanSampson suggests IE mode, compatability mode etc.

Comment: @JonathanSampson, you were right about the Document Mode property. They are different from each other. Please see my edit, and many thankful thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we determined in the comments above, the cause was due to different document modes locally and remotely. The cause of this could be any number of things:

1. Developer tools were overriding the document mode.
2. An `x-ua-compatible` header is being sent locally, or remotely with the HTTP response.
3. Additional markup when being viewed remotely is invalidating an otherwise valid document.
4. Local or remote instances are being loaded with an explicit `x-ua-compatible` meta tag.

These are the primary reasons you will notice a difference in document modes. Start by checking your developer tools to ensure you weren't merely overriding the default document mode.

Check your markup (likely the `<header>` portion) for an `x-ua-compatible` meta tag. If one isn't found there, check the HTTP response headers for it there.

Comment: After some researches on the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag, I've tried to put `<httpProtocol><customerHeaders><add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=9" /></customerHeaders></httpProtocol>` and that did it!

Comment: @WillMarcouiller Remember, that's only a *temporary* solution. You should find out what is causing the site to fall back to the IE 7 Document Mode, and resolve that issue. The `x-ua-compatible` approach is meant only as a band-aid until you can address the root-cause. Glad this helped!

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. Solution was to get rid of compatibilty mode for intranet sites in IE. [MS Support IE compatibility modes infos](http://support.microsoft.com/de-de/kb/2536204)